# Image manipulation with SailsJS

Tags: node.js, sails.js, image-manipulation

Has anyone made a sails app with skipper-s3 and image manipulation library to upload different sizes of images ?

For example if a user upload a user profile image then there will be three different sizes of images will be uploaded to the S3 server. Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: I use a combination of filepicker.io with blitline.com to handle that. Not exactly and answer to your question, but might be helpful.

Comment: You can use a custom receiver with graphicsmagick as found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069203/skipper-in-sailsjs-beta-image-resize-before-upload)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ImageMagick-Native](https://github.com/mash/node-imagemagick-native) to do the resizing before uploadng to S3, like this:

```
var resBuff = imagemagick.convert({
   srcData: originalBuffer,
   width: X, //dimensions in pixel
   height: Y,
   resizeStyle: "aspectfill",
   quality: 80,
   format: 'JPEG'
});
```

The `resBuff` object can now be uploaded to s3 as the resized image.